# PartialView doesn't Get fully in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this PartialVIew :

```
@model IEnumerable<Tungsten.Models.ProductGroup>
<div id="treeviewpglist" class="filetree">
    <ul id="tree" class="treeview">
        <li><span class="folder"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="treenode"><input type="hidden" value="12">Name</a></span></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="pgID">
</div>
```

and I load it in a view with this code :

```
$.get('@Url.Action( "GroupList" , "Product" )', function (data) { $('#treeviewdiv div').replaceWith(data); }).success(function ()
{
    // do something
});
```

its work fine in chrome, Firefox and IE9. but in IE8 or IE9-Compatibility View
the code doenst get fully loaded and its load something like this

```
<div id="treeviewdiv">
    <a class="treenode selected" onclick="return false;" href="#">
        <input value=12 type=hidden>Name
    </a>
    <input id=pgID type=hidden> 
</div>
```

how can i fix it?

```
$('#treeviewdiv div').load('@Url.Action( "GroupList" , "Product" )', function ()
{
    $('#treeviewdiv .treenode').click(function ()
    {
        $('#treeviewdiv .treenode').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#pgID').val($(this).children(':hidden').val());
        LoadProduct();
    });
});
```

In IE8 or IE9-Compatibility View the **$(this).children(':hidden').val()** is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Is what you get an older version of the partial view?

IE Caches GET requests.  A way round this is to add an extra query string parameter of current ticks, or a random number, to make the url unique.

Alternatively you could switch from using the `$.get` method to using `$.ajax` and setting `cache:false`, which does the same thing

**Example**

```
var url = '@Url.Action( "GroupList" , "Product" )';
var queryString = '?timespan=' + new Date().getTime();
$.get(url + queryString , 
    function (data) { $('#treeviewdiv div').replaceWith(data); 
});
```

Comment: i try $.load() and its work fine
but i got some problem with .children()

Comment: Where are you using .children()?